# how does method sleep works in java

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Producer implements Runnable
{
   private static final SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();
   private final Buffer sharedLocation; // reference to shared object

   // constructor
   public Producer(Buffer sharedLocation)
   {
      this.sharedLocation = sharedLocation;
   } 

   // store values from 1 to 10 in sharedLocation
   public void run()                             
   {
      int sum = 0;

      for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
      {
         try // sleep 0 to 3 seconds, then place value in Buffer
         {
            Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(3000)); // random sleep
            sharedLocation.blockingPut(count); // set value in buffer
            sum += count; // increment sum of values
            System.out.printf("\t%2d%n", sum);
         } 
         catch (InterruptedException exception) 
         {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
         } 
      } 

      System.out.printf(
         "Producer done producing%nTerminating Producer%n");
   } 
} // end class Producer
```

I don't understand the "try-catch" part of it:
isn't method sleep() the one that will throw the InterruptedException() and thus the try block will terminate and the catch block will execute?
Then how did we write statements after the sleep() statement in the try block,i.e. they will not execute right?

Comment: They won't execute if the sleep is interrupted. If the sleep completes, they are executed.

Comment: To build on what Andy said a little more, `Thread.sleep` only throws an `InterruptedException` if the thread is externally interrupted. It doesn't throw this exception if it sleeps for the full 0-3 seconds (whatever random number is picked).

Comment: Note that the try/catch should be around the loop: as it stands, because of the `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, the sleep on the next loop iteration will be interrupted immediately, then you call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, the sleep on the next loop iteration will be interrupted immediately, etc. You may as well just give up on the loop once it is interrupted.

Comment: And unless you can explain exactly why you need a `SecureRandom`, you don't need one. Just use `Random`, as it's significantly lighter weight.

Comment: @chrylis actually i don't know why the book is using SecureRandom instead of Random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Thread.sleep` completes normally, any subsequent statements will be executed. It is only if the thread is interrupted before or during the `sleep` that those statements won't be executed.

Note that the try/catch should be around the loop: as it stands, because of the `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, the sleep on the next loop iteration will be interrupted immediately, then you call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, the sleep on the next loop iteration will be interrupted immediately, etc.

You may as well just give up on the loop once it is interrupted:

```
try {
  for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
  {
     Thread.sleep(generator.nextInt(3000)); // random sleep
     // ...
  }
} catch (InterruptedException exception) {
  Thread.currentThread().interupt(); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why do we interrupt the thread again in the catch clause (in your edited code and the original one)after it has been interrupted by an external factor(e.g. the main thread)?Isn't the interruption enough to be done once to inform the method to stop looping and do something else?